# How to make a new column that filled with dictionary, with the certain key and certain value from other column

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

[HERE IS THE PICTURE OF TABLE OF DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMv6U.png)

I wanna ask, how to make a new column that filled with dictionaries. With the key is all the date between booking_check_in  to booking_check_out and the value assigned by the value of the column 'average'

So, for example, from the first row there will be a column that contain of dictionary, like this
{2019-11-01}.
Then, from the second row there will be a column that contain this dictionary
{2019-11-01 : 32,
2019-11-02 : 32,
2019-11-03 : 32}

I have tried it, like this:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
grup_usd['delta'] = grup_usd['booking_check_in'] - grup_usd['booking_check_out']       # as timedelta

for i in range(grup_usd['diff_day_int']):
    day = grup_usd['booking_check_in'] + timedelta(days=i)
    print(day)
```

but, it end like this
[Like this picture shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjJYX.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Guidelines ([ask]) request that you post your data as code and not as image. Check out [example] as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use a [**`DataFrame.apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) across rows (`axis=1`).

Generate the [**`date_range()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) from `booking_check_in` to `booking_check_out` and `zip()` them with the averages:

```py
def average_by_date(row):
    dates = pd.date_range(row.booking_check_in, row.booking_check_out).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')[:-1]
    averages = [row.average] * len(dates)
    return dict(zip(dates, averages))
    
grup_usd['average_by_date'] = grup_usd.apply(average_by_date, axis=1)

#   booking_check_in booking_check_out booking_earned diff_day_int average                                   average_by_date
# 0       2019-11-01        2019-11-02           48.0            1    48.0                              {'2019-11-01': 48.0}
# 1       2019-11-01        2019-11-04           96.0            3    32.0 {'2019-11-01': 32.0, '2019-11-02': 32.0, '2019...
# 2       2019-11-01        2019-11-02           50.0            1    50.0                              {'2019-11-01': 50.0}
# 3       2019-11-01        2019-11-05          252.0            4    63.0 {'2019-11-01': 63.0, '2019-11-02': 63.0, '2019...
```